# React create issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I've started a course to learn React and I'm having
trouble in developmental setup.
In the previous course, I used browser-sync and in this course the teacher used lite-server, so I installed that. But now, on creating react app, I'm having this error and I can't understand, please help.
I'm new to the whole npm, node.js environment.

**Screenshot of Error**

[image: pic1]

Comment: `npm start` is a create-react app magic.
If you want to use npm script commands you have to run: `npm run <scrip>` .
The <script> commands are listed in package.json under the scripts. 
Can you write here what scripts are in the package.json under the scrips?

Comment: "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run lite",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "lite": "lite-server"
  },

Comment: In your case try to run: `npm run start` <= This script is equal with: `npm run lite`. `npm run lite` is pointing to your last script, what is staring a `lite-server`.

Comment: You are also able to run a test with `npm run test` what is just echoing that no test specified.